# Is pandas .between() faster than using &?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that the user can apply a variety of filters on using sliders to specify a min and max value.  Right now there are seven filters, but there may be more added in the future.

I currently have the filter definition as:

```
filt = ( (df['A']>= sliderA[0]) & (df['A']<sliderA[1]) &
         (df['B']>= sliderB[0]) & (df['B']<sliderB[1]) & 
         etc...)
```

Would it be computationally faster to use pandas' built-in `.between()` operator?

```
filt = ( df['A'].between(sliderA[0], sliderA[1]) & 
       ...)
```

My gut tells me no, since it would be going out and executing a separate function as opposed to writing out the evaluation in lower level.  But my gut is also very hungry.

I don't think the speed is a big issue yet, but I can see in the future where it might become more important.

Comment: This is an empirical question... Did you try and profile this for yourself?

Comment: I have not.  I don't know how to time things in order to compare.

Comment: I have discovered the %timeit function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `%timeit` function, I got the following results:

| Filter | operator | mean | st dev |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | `.between()` | 274us | 19.8us |
| 1 | `&` | 282us | 11.3us |
| 2 | `.between()` | 265us | 2.64us |
| 2 | `&` | 265us | 9.66us |

Filter 1 example:

```
%timeit df['cpu_rank'].between(0,222)
%timeit (df['cpu_rank']>=0) & (df['cpu_rank']<=222)
```

Overall, not a great deal of difference, or at least not enough to warrant the work required to convert from `&` to `.between()`